# How do I reference the properties of a reference type dictionary key?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I'm working on a chess engine, and I'm currently implementing the transposition table (a set of already evaluated board positions from past moves). The general idea is that when a move is made, I check the transposition table for a matching position. If it exists, I skip the costly evaluation process and just pull the previously calculated results from the transposition table. If it doesn't exist, I do the required calculations and then add it to the transposition table for future reference.

To me, this sounds like a job for a hashset or a dictionary. I decided upon the dictionary. I wanted the key to be the class representing my board, and the value to be an int count of how many times the position has been encountered. The reason for the count is to be able to detect a threefold repetition draw. If the same position has been encountered three or more times, the player has the option to call a draw. Using a dictionary instead of a hashset allows me to greatly simplify the detection of a threefold repetition draw by combining it with my transposition table.

In order to do this, I've made the class that represents a board's state override Equals() and GetHashCode(). It works just fine, and I now am able to keep track of all of the historical states that a game previously encountered.

My problem is that I need to be able to access the properties of the key object in the dictionary. I can see whether a match exists (by using the .ContainsKey(...) method and my Equals()/GetHashCode() logic), but now I need to pull the previously mentioned calculated values (stored as public properties of my board state object) from the key.

I was able to come up with:

```
BoardState board = TranspositionTable.Keys.FirstOrDefault(tt => tt.GetHashCode() == this.GetHashCode());
```

This works, but feels clunky to me. The whole point of the transposition table is to speed up a recursive search of millions of successive board states. Querying a dictionary for each match just sounds counter-intuitive. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

As it's been pointed out, my hash couldn't be perfect due to the huge number of valid board states. My Equals() override checks a second alternatively generated hash to reduce the possibilities of collisions. My above 'solution' is flawed, as it relys on an imperfect hash. I should have used:

```
BoardState board = TranspositionTable.Keys.FirstOrDefault(tt => tt.Equals(this));
```

A stupid oversight on my part. Still, I'm not a fan a querying dictionaries.

Comment: what exactly is the key in your dictionary ? can make the result of `GetHashCode()` the key ? If so, then this becomes much more "natural" to handle...

Comment: @Yahia hash codes, by their very nature, are not unique, so you'd need to support a list of objects as the value and use `Equals` to find the *true* equal object with that hash code.

Comment: @Servy that's true... but the OP seems to be happy with any result matching the hash code (according to the code shown)...

Comment: @Yahia Which he shouldn't be.  The code he posted is broken.

Comment: he has implemented his own Hashcode, so perhaps it *is* unique now? OP, is this the case? If so....

Comment: @Servy I can't know whether he should or should not be happy with it... although it is a bit weird...

Comment: @Yahia The hash isn't perfect, which is where the Equals() comes in. I have a checksum (a second hashing algorithm) that Equals() checks in addition to the checksum. It's true that my lambda doesn't account for potential collisions of the primary hash. I hadn't considered that. I should use Equals instead.

Comment: @baldric We *know* what it represents; it represents the state of a chess board.  I'm pretty sure there are more than 2^32 possible board states.

Comment: @baldric very true. If there were only that many, someone would have created a database of perfect moves per position. My Equals() method checks a second hash to minimize the chance of collisions. I'll update my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Chronicide Since you have not created a "100% unique/collision-free hash" my option won't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to just hold a reference to the key in the value of the dictionary, as well as the *actual* value of the dictionary, like so:

```
Dictionary<BoardState, Tuple<BoardState, int>>
```

Then whenever you add an object add the same object to the value as to the key:

```
Dictionary<BoardState, Tuple<BoardState, int>> boards = 
    new Dictionary<BoardState,Tuple<BoardState,int>>();
BoardState board = new BoardState();
boards.Add(board, Tuple.Create(board, 1));
```

The other option (which is probably better design) is to break up your board state object into two different types.  Have one which really does just represent the state of the board (this should be immutable), and another that holds the other information about that state including the times it has occurred and any other *mutable* attributes that may apply to your specific application.  This would prevent you from needing to access the dictionary key.

Comment: I like the idea of separating out the state... It isn't the easy solution, but it feels like the right direction to take.

Comment: I should also note that I chose your answer because your first solution not only answers my question, but also implies that there is no easy way to access properties of a key directly (which was what I was acting, in my own long-winded round about way). Just as an aside, another solution to my particular situation would be to run a hashset for the transposition table, and a separate dictionary for the three-fold repetition rule. This has the added benefit of the disambiguation, where each is responsible for one thing and nothing else.